# Find the real and imaginary part of $i^{37}+i^{22}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I haven't quite understood yet how to solve questions like this:

name the real part and the imaginary part of
$z= i^{37}+i^{22}$

Am I supposed to do this with polar coordinates or is there a trick because of the power?

Comment: Polar coordinates are not needed. Start by calculating the powers of $i$: $i^1$, $i^2$, $i^3$, $i^4$, $i^5$,....., and spot the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

> or is there a trick because of the power?

Yes!

Hint: $i^4=1$, so we also have $i^8=1$ and $i^{12}=1$ and...

Can you now calculate $i^{22}$ and $i^{37}$?

Comment: so: i^22=-1 and i^37=1 ; is the answer then just zero?

Comment: Your calculation for $i^{37}$ seems to be off

Comment: ohhh! i^37=i, so the real part is 1 and the imaginary part is 1 as well...?

Comment: I think so too!

Comment: thank you so much!!!